# Kids Account Uncontrollable in Family Management

Tags: ps4

I have had my kids account on the PS4 for many years, but it is time to manage the time and I cannot. They have a long time established account, which I can add to Family Management, but I cannot do any parental controls or time management on it. I created a new account which I now CAN control, however all the Rainbow 6 Siege saved data is not associated, is it possible to move that to another account on the PS4?

Answer (score 1):

Save data transfer? No.
You may have set your kids to a higher permission when they were made. If that is the case, nothing can be done.